# Computer architecture: Count of RAM, ROM and I/O interface addressing

Tags: homework, computer-architecture, ram, addressing, rom

I am trying to work through this question and I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you

Problem:
A computer system uses RAM chips of size 512x8 and ROM chips of size 256x8. The computer system needs 4k bytes of RAM, 1k bytes of ROM, and 16 I/O interface units. A memory-mapped I/O configuration is used.

1. How many RAM and ROM chips are needed?
2. how many address lines are needed?
3. give the address range in hexadecimal for RAM, ROM, and I/O interface units.

Solution:

1. 4000 bytes divided by 512 bytes is 8. So we need 8 RAM chips. Similarly, 1000 bytes divided by 256 bytes is 4. So we need 4 ROM chips. Not sure how relevant was "16 I/O interface units" here because I didn't use it.
2. we need 12 bits to represent the addresses.
3. 0x0000 - 0x0F9F for RAM (4000 bytes and addresses are in bytes), 0x0FA0-0x1387 for ROM (1000 bytes). 0x1388-0x1397 for I/O (16 lines).

Am I on the right track?

Comment: 4k might mean 4096 vs the decimal 4000. Generally a ‘k’ when talking about memory size implies 1024.

Comment: Are you sure about the amount of address lines? How many bytes to you need to address and how many bits do you need to represent that number? Also make sure that, in your textbook, 1K actually means 1000 and not a "binary K" (1024 = 2^10).

Comment: @Kartman the convention, AFAIK, is to use "capital K" or "Ki" (kibi) when talking about  binary kilobytes (powers of two).

Comment: @StarCat Even if conventions between k and K exist, isn't that unofficial, and while kibibytes does exist as an IEC unit, nobody really uses them as it makes things even more confusing. And context is clear. Nobody sells memory chips with 1000 or 4000 adresses. They will have 1024 and 4096 addresses.

Comment: Q3- Use 4k or 8k chunks. A 3 bits decoder/demux 1/8 will do it easily. https://ece-research.unm.edu/jimp/310/slides/8086_memory2.html Addresses of EEPROM can be the lowest OR the highest depending of microprocessor used (6800 or 8085 or 6502 or ...)

Comment: @Justme, I agree, inventing kibibytes has not made things clearer, especially for those of us used to powers-of-2 "Kilo/Mega/Giga".